# Como Guardar datos de un Select para consultar en la BD?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, formularios

tengo un sistema Login para generar desprendibles de pago en mi compañía: tengo un formulario con tres campos para el login entre ellos un campo Select el cual necesito utilizar para la consulta de datos del empleado una vez se logre el login. Adicional tengo un php para validar el Login con datos de la BD, al final del ejercicio se debe carga una pagina con los datos de la consulta a la bd que debería utilizar como criterio de filtro la identificación del empleado `$_SESSION['identificacion']` y el dato del campo Select pero no logro que funciones del todo no se donde estoy fallando, espero me puedan ayudar:

Login:

```
<form method="POST" action="loginProceso.php">
<label>Usuario: </label>
<input type="text" name="caja1">
<br>
<label>Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="caja3">
<br>
<label>Rango: </label>
<select name="caja2" >
<option>mes 1</option>
<option>mes 2</option>
<input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión">
</form>
```

Funcion para el Login:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include_once 'model/conexion.php';
    $usuario = $_POST['caja1'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['caja3'];
    $sentencia = $bd->prepare('select * from t_usuario where 
                                nombre_usu = ? and password_usu = ?;');
    $sentencia->execute([$usuario, $contrasena]);
    $datos = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($datos);

    if ($datos === FALSE) {
        header('Location: logindesp.php');
    }elseif($sentencia->rowCount() == 1){
        $_SESSION['identificacion'] = $datos->nombre_usu;
        header('Location: desprendibleSB.php');
    }
?>
```

Pagina Índex luego del login:

```
<?php  
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])) {
    header('Location: logindesp.php');
}elseif(isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])){
    include 'model/conexion.php';
    $sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM laboral WHERE emp_id = '".$_SESSION['identificacion']."' and rango = '".$_POST['caja2']."';");
    $empleado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($empleado);
}else{
    echo "Error en el sistema";
}

include 'model/closeconexion.php';

foreach ($empleado as $dato) {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Certificado</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloscert.css" />
</head>

<body>

<section class="section-table cid-spXjgZGvMA" id="table1-is">

<div class="container">
        <div class="media-container-row">
            <div class="mbr-text col-12 col-md-8 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                <blockquote><strong>PERIODO LIQUIDADO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Rango; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>NOMBRE COMPLETO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Nombre; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>IDENTIFICACIÓN</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Cedula; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>CARGO DESEMPEÑADO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Cargo; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>DIAS LABORADOS</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Dl; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>PUESTO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Centrocosto; ?> </span></blockquote></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?  }  ?>
```

Comment: ¿Si fuerzas el `print_r($empleado);` obtienes algo?  No especificas que falla realmente. Ahora no se si es la consulta o la visualización de los datos.  Además, en el select no pones ningún `<option value="lo que sea">`, por lo tanto `caja2` siempre sera un valor vacio.

Comment: **Notice: Undefined index: caja2 in C:\wamp64\www\bd\desprendible.php on line 7**  `$sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT *..........` esta linea seria la del error pero no detecto que pasa o que falta para que haga la doble comparación en la BD. Y 
`<option value="lo que sea">` se llena con una consulta a la base de datos y trae los nombres de cada mes con un adicional "Enero quince 1... etc etc" y funciona bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo ese error es porque en **desprendible.php** no existe la variable **$caja2**, puesto que esa variable yace en el **loginProceso.php**. Si quieres pasar ese parámetro puedes usar otra variable de sesión con el rango.

El **loginProceso.php** quedaría así:

```php
<?php 
    session_start();
    include_once 'model/conexion.php';
    $usuario = $_POST['caja1'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['caja3'];
    $sentencia = $bd->prepare('select * from t_usuario where 
                                nombre_usu = ? and password_usu = ?;');
    $sentencia->execute([$usuario, $contrasena]);
    $datos = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($datos);

    if ($datos === FALSE) {
        header('Location: logindesp.php');
    }elseif($sentencia->rowCount() == 1){
        $_SESSION['identificacion'] = $datos->nombre_usu;
        $_SESSION['rango'] = $_POST['caja2'];//Guardo el rango para usarlo despues
        header('Location: desprendibleSB.php');
    }
?>
```

Y el **index.php**

```php
<?php  
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])) {
    header('Location: logindesp.php');
}elseif(isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])){
    include 'model/conexion.php';
    $sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM laboral WHERE emp_id = '".$_SESSION['identificacion']."' and rango = '".$_SESSION['rango']."';");
    $empleado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($empleado);
}else{
    echo "Error en el sistema";
}

include 'model/closeconexion.php';

foreach ($empleado as $dato) {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Certificado</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloscert.css" />
</head>

<body>

<section class="section-table cid-spXjgZGvMA" id="table1-is">

<div class="container">
        <div class="media-container-row">
            <div class="mbr-text col-12 col-md-8 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                <blockquote><strong>PERIODO LIQUIDADO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Rango; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>NOMBRE COMPLETO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Nombre; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>IDENTIFICACIÓN</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Cedula; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>CARGO DESEMPEÑADO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Cargo; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>DIAS LABORADOS</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Dl; ?> </span>
                <br><strong>PUESTO</strong>: <span style="font-style: normal;"><?php echo $dato->Centrocosto; ?> </span></blockquote></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php  }  ?>
```

Bueno, finalmente como recomendación te sugiero que los nombres de los campos(input name) sean mas descriptivo, por ejemplo  en vez de que se llame *caja2* se llame *rango*.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Excelente @jsan5709 aunque casi me parto la cabeza con el cierre final del PHP `<?  }  ?>` era `<?php  }  ?>` y no sabia por que arrojaba error jejeje, gracias ya quedo resuelto el problema mil mil gracias